# What function would do this

Tags: functions, parity

I need a function $f(n)$ that if $n$ is odd it returns $-1$, but if it is even it returns $1$. Is there a function like this? If so what is it? Also I would appreciate if it is not a trig function *(Ahem $f(n) = \cos(n\pi)$)*.

Comment: Yes, there is such a function. You have just defined it. Congratulations!

Comment: Every function on the integers of period 2 is a linear combination of the powers of the two second roots of unity. i.e. It's $a(-1)^n+b(1)^n$ for some $a$ and $b$. Matt Samuel's answer exhibits $a$ and $b$. Crash's answer elaborates on Henning Makholm's comment: saying what a function does on every input is defining that function. We consider $\cos(n\pi)$, $(-1)^n$, and "the function on the integers that outputs $-1$ when the input is odd and $1$ otherwise" to all refer to the same function.

Comment: You need to specify your domain and codomain. The answer provided by @angryavian is probably the simplest. Note that my answer is literally what you described translated into mathematics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have defined is already a function, but I assume what you want is an elementary expression for it. Try
$$(-1)^{n}$$

Answer (score 2):

I think this works as well.
$$f(n):= (-1)^n$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider $f\colon\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$ defined by
$$
f(n)=
\begin{cases}
-1 &\text{if} & n=2k+1, k\in\mathbb{Z},\\
1 &\text{if} & n=2k, k\in\mathbb{Z}.
\end{cases}
$$